# ASP.NET Core Identity with IdentityServer and Xamarin Native

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to login from a Xamarin Android App and Xamarin iOS app to an ASP.NET Core Web App using Identity and it isn't working. Has anyone tried Xamarin with IdentityServer4 and the standard ASP.NET core identity out of the box? E.g. Use aspnetusers table created by identity and all the user registration features while identityserver provides token stores for mobile app?

Comment: "what are your thoughts" is not really an on-topic question for SO.

Comment: I am blank here. I think I should rephrase it.